# Getting SIGSEGV in std::map, when using find function

Tags: c++, gdb, stdmap, segmentation-fault

I am running some small online game and there is server crash at some time. I can't find what is causing the SIGSEGV. The gdb bring me to that function:

```
bool Player::getStorageValue(const uint32_t key, int32_t& value) const
{
    auto it = storageMap.find(key);
    if (it == storageMap.end()) {
        value = -1;
        return false;
}

    value = it->second;
    return true;
}
```

Can I somehow protect it better to not let program attempt to access a restricted area of memory?

And heres my gdb log:

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x000000000054503c in std::less<unsigned int>::operator()(unsigned int const&, unsigned int const&) const ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x0000000000740dca in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, int> > >::_M_lower_bound(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, int> > const*, std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned int const, int> > const*, unsigned int const&) const ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x000000000073e145 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, std::pair<unsigned int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned int const, int> >, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, int> > >::find(unsigned int const&) const ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x000000000073c46f in std::map<unsigned int, int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, int> > >::find(unsigned int const&) const ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x000000000072dfa2 in Player::getStorageValue(unsigned int, int&) const ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00000000006b2890 in LuaScriptInterface::luaPlayerGetStorageValue(lua_State*) ()
```

I've added the mutex to code to don't let threads attempt to some elements at the same time

```
bool Player::getStorageValue(const uint32_t key, int32_t& value) const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockClass(mutex_gp13);

    auto it = storageMap.find(key);
    if (it == storageMap.end()) {
        value = -1;
        return false;
    }

    value = it->second;
    return true;
}
```

I though that should solve my problem, but today had the same SIGSEGV with that gdb log.

Edit:
I found that I didn't put mutex on function that writes to the map. Im gonna try with this now.

Comment: It looks like your map got corrupted. The code here is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this is a server I'm thinking you might be multi-threading.  If this is the case it could be that your map is being altered somewhere before you set the return value causing your iterator to become invalid.  You then access the invalid iterator and the program dies horribly.

If this is the case then you'll need to protect it from change with a semaphore or the like.  If not then we're probably going to need a bit more information because the code looks good.

Comment: So the main problem is that theres possibility that some threads could edit some element there at the same time? I'll try put mutex there then.

Comment: I thought It was okay, the error didnt occur for 2 days, but today I just had one with the same gdb log. Mutex didn't helped me here, its weird.

Comment: I found that I made not working properly mutex, gonna test it now with better one

Comment: @Piodo Word of advice with mutexes and semaphores.  I tend to avoid problems later on by using a mutex for each member variable or group of member variables that are being accessed by outside threads.  Name them appropriately so you know what mutex is locking which variable or group.  Becareful of thread lock.  Doing too much processing by an outside thread can cause you to lock your threads up where each is waiting on the other to finish.  Always lock and unlock in the same function.  Lastly, practice.  Threading is HARD.  Learning threading is harder.  Don't give up.

Answer (score 0):

This server is Open Tibia Server and I get same stack from gdb after calling:

```
player->getStorageValue(123, value)
```

on **player** which is **Player*** and points to removed variable.
C++ code is fine and mutex won't fix it.

Problem is with LUA scripts loaded by server, which may call functions on removed objects. I described common bugs in LUA scripts here: https://halp.skalski.pro/2020/06/05/tfs-1-x-how-to-not-write-lua-scripts-or-how-to-crash-server-by-lua-script/